# iPhone/iPad landscape orientation and UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, ipad, orientation, screen-orientation

I am using Sparrow framework, and also I am forcing my app to be only in landscape orientation. I have a button in my app, clicking on which opens UIAlertView. However, if I rotate (change orientation from say landscape right to landscape left (meaning that home button is either on the right or left)) and click on the button to open UIAlertView -- it opens it but upside down!
How do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed with

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation: [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation animated: NO ];
```

in

```
-(void)orientationDetected:(UIEvent *)event
```

Comment: Keyboard is shifted in somehow.